# Power Query Create conditional new column

Tags: powerquery

I am having a little challenge.
In the attached sample data you can see that for a single AMI two different Product names exist.I do know that when that occurs only Linux/UNIX is correct. I would like to create a new column that will be looking for each AMI if it has 2 distinct string values then the new column to always be Linux/UNIX.

İmage

[image]

For the time being, i am using in power query text.contains and i specify manually those AMIs but this is not so productive. I am not aware if i can run loops with power query.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Filippos

Answer (score 0):

Group the data on Ami and count Product names; merge results back into table; add custom column that checks the new column like **=if [newcolumn] >1 then "Linux" else null**

Another possibility. Sort table. Click to select product and type column then right click remove duplicates, which should only keep first instance. If you sorted correctly, then all the non Linuxes will be removed

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. My intention is not to remove the data if it is dupe just to correct the product name from RHEL to Linux. This is a problem in my data source and trying to" fix it". Also, i am importing this data into power pivot data model using power query and i want to do this via power query,

Comment: Just to explain a little more. This is sample data.  I am importing into my data model more than 10.000 rows daily and i have more than 100 different AMIs .The problem is that the csv i am receiving from my data source has this error. As you know each AMI can only be Linux or RHEL. I want while importing the new data into my data model to force and create a new column that can identify if a single AMI has 2 distict product names, and if that occurs to force the name in the new column to always be Linux.